# How to add a space in front of every line in notepad

Tags: space, notepad

I have a list of data in notepad and want to insert a space in the beginning of each line.

**Example**

This is how it looks in the notepad now

```
Number

"123"

"123"

"124"

"126"

"147"
```

I want it to look like below

```
    Number

    "123"

    "123"

    "124"

    "126"

    "147"
```

I am sure there is some short cut. Please advice.

Comment: found a similar question on superuser [find and replace](http://superuser.com/questions/637476/using-wildcard-search-replace-in-notepad)

Answer (score 22):

Open your file in Notepad++

Press Ctrl+H to open the Replace window.

Change the "Search Mode" to Regular expression.

In the "Find what" box, type `(\n|^)`

In the "Replace with" box, type `\1`     (with your spaces or tab at the end)

Then click "Replace All"

**Note:** If you want tabs instead of spaces, a tab character can be typed with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>

Comment: @FilippoG If you're adding code on SO, simply select the code and click the button that looks like `{}`. SO will add the spaces for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is for notepad pre-installed with ubuntu:

1.Select the lines you want to indent

2.click `tab`

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt and select the line no. move curser till the line no you want to have space . Now you can enter spaces as many you want or anything and save it.